# How should I write a selector in sass/css to apply for class, not having another class in entire path?

Tags: css, sass

It is easier to explain using the next example:
[image]

I want to apply a bunch of styles (for example, for `.footer` element) if the element is inside a class named `.ct_ver1`, but I also want to except (do not apply) the styles if the element is inside a class `.ct_ver2`.

In result it should be:

-- no classes - do not apply styles

-- class `ct_ver1` element - apply styles to the element

-- class `ct_ver1` * `ct_ver2` element - do not apply styles

In my current approch it does not work because, I have another div (`ct_ver1_container`) in the tree, therefore the `ct_ver2` is ignored,
because the selector find the `.footer` using this path:
`ct_ver` -> `ct_ver1_container` -> `footer`

but I want to ignore (do not apply styles) if there is a div with a class `ct_ver2` in the path on any level.

How should I write correct code?

My current code looks like:

```
.ct_ver1 {
  div:not(.ct_ver2) {
    .footer {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please add html also

Comment: html can be generated dynamically. so it can be changed. but I showed you an example of some html on the screenshot.

Comment: even classes will change??

Comment: yes. the only classes you can work with (that will not be changed) will be `ct_ver1` and `ct_ver2`

Comment: then you can directly target like this .ct_ver1 .footer{}

Comment: No. I cannot, the `.footer` can be inside `ct_ver2`. which can be inside `ct_ver1`. In such cases I must not apply styles.

Comment: Inside only 2 classes??

Comment: Ok, I will exapain in another words. Imagine, you have a website, with it's own styles, and you add some widget (div block) with it's own styles to this page and you want that the website styles do not apply your block. How will you do this? You have to isolate your block from website styles. like iframe. But, ofcourse it should not be an iframe.